# How to find and extract the numbers from string in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to asp.net can you help me to find out how to find and extract the numbers from string in Asp.net.

Comment: can you please explain more with some example ?

Answer (score 0):

```
string output = new string(input.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray());
```

Comment: This way is very slow

Comment: @ShahroozJefriㇱ depends on length of the string

Comment: Yes but regix is better

Comment: A regex isn't free either. You won't notice a thing for both methods, you're too focused on premature optimization.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

```
       String str = "udsdf34dfd78"; /*any string*/
       String strNumber = "";
       Regex regex=new Regex(@"\d");

       foreach (Match m in regex.Matches(str))
           strNumber += m.Value;
```

**Method 2:**

```
              String str = "udsdf34dfd78"; /*any string*/
              String strNumber = ""; 
              foreach (Char c in str)
               if (Char.IsDigit(c))
                   strNumber += c.ToString();
```